# Computer won't start up (PSU tested out ok)

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I've got a ten year old computer that was working until recently.  Now it won't start.  When you turn it on, nothing at all happens - no fans turn on (including on PSU), no lights on the mobo light up.  I bought a PSU tester, and it tested out fine.  I've tried taking out all components and put in a new CMOS battery, but still won't power up.  Is there anything else worth trying?

Comment: If the PSU is good, the only other thing it could be is a bad power switch or motherboard (or bad/loose connection between PSU and motherboard).

Comment: You might find this troubleshooting flowchart useful, it's saved my bacon a few times: https://www.fonerbooks.com/power.htm